# Framework .NET. Difference between lot of Dll and one Exe only

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll, .net-assembly

I'm building a WinForms application. I would like to know if there are difference between one only .exe file or multiple Dll. Actually i have 7Mb of one .exe, and i fear of some performance issue; but i've read the Framework loads all needed Dll at startup, so the assembly fragmetation is useless. Is right?

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. Dependent assemblies are loaded on demand, not at startup.

Answer (score 6):

> but i've read the Framework loads all needed Dll at startup

It loads them *as it finds it needs them*; this tends to mean that *many* are neded at startup, but there is no magic "find everything I will ever need and load it now" step. In particular, assemblies are usually loaded when JIT finds a type reference in a dll that isn't currently loaded.

Note, however, that in many ways a single large assembly is not problematic - JIT is per-type; it doesn't look at every type in the assembly when it loads it. As the same time, though - while assembly resolution / verification / fusion can get noticeable if you have *too many* dlls, that is only going to matter for very large numbers; a handful or a dozen or so isn't going to matter much (indeed, the .NET framework itself is split into many separate dlls).

In most scenarios, any startup performance relates mainly to the **things your code does** at startup - any processing of external configuration, etc. The choice of 1 assembly vs 5 (or whatever) is rarely going to be a critical factor.

For info, a quick winform test shows that any winforms usage is going to involve *at least* 6 dlls - most likely more (as you add features, etc):

```
{your application}
mscorlib
System.Windows.Forms
System
System.Drawing
Accessibility
```

via:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        using (var form = new Form()) {
            Application.Run(form);
        }
        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            Console.WriteLine(assembly.GetName().Name);
    }
}
```